# Videos won't stop playing even when released

Tags: objective-c, video, uiwebview, release

This is probably a fairly simple answer but I just can't manage to fix it myself.

So in my app, I have a page that loads with 3 videos playing on the screen, embedded in web views. All I want is for the videos to stop playing when they navigate back to the previous page because at the moment, if the video is playing when they click back, the audio will continue to play in the background. This is even though I have released the web views:

-(void)dealloc {

```
[webView1 release];
[webView2 release];
[webView3 release];
[super dealloc];
```

}

No matter what I try, they continue to play!
Any ideas anybody?

Thanks,

Matt

Answer (score 0):

I'm only guessing here but it looks like you have a hybrid app (native code + HTML/JS/CSS).

I'll assume that the videos are being played in an HTML5 video player?

In that case, when the video starts, it's actually being handed off to a native instance of `MPMoviePlayerController` that is likely outside of your control.

However, releasing a web view won't be enough to stop the video, probably because ownership of the video player is outside of the web view. You'll have to run some kind of javascript to stop the video when navigating back.

Of course, this relies on the assumption that you have a hybrid app.

Comment: Not native, it is all in Xcode or Objective-C.

The videos are local files that are being loaded in to the web view so unless it does it automatically, I don't think its a HTML5 video player, not sure about that one though.

Comment: "Native Code" does mean Objective-C in this regard. So it is native, and not hybrid. why are you loading local videos into a web view to play them? Why not use `MPMoviePlayerController` which will give you more control?

Comment: Sorry, I did mean to say not hybrid.
And I didn't use MPMoviePlayer because I was having issues getting them to work and this way seemed to work fine and I found it easier to understand.
But if MPMoviePlayerControllers would be better, I could probably take another look. I'm guessing it's still not that tricky so I will give it a shot. Do you have any tips when using them? Thanks very much for your help so far :D

Comment: Everything you need to know is in the documentation for `MPMoviePlayerController` http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/MediaPlayer/Reference/MPMoviePlayerController_Class/Reference/Reference.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40006953. You'll need to link against the MediaPlayer framework as well.

Comment: Ok, I now have code creating, initialising and loading the 3 movies into the MPMoviePlayerController. But it only likes playing the last video that is loaded. I know you can only have one video playing at a time, but it doesn't let me play the other at all, there is no play button on them. I don't know if this is something to do with the fact I am embedding them in a scroll view or if I'm just missing something

Comment: My code is:  NSString *path = [[NSBundle mainBundle] pathForResource:@"BenMontague" ofType:@"m4v"];
    NSURL *url = [NSURL fileURLWithPath:path];
    MPMoviePlayerController *movieController = [[MPMoviePlayerController alloc] initWithContentURL:url];
    [movieController.view setFrame:CGRectMake(20, 20, 196, 105)];
    [scrollView addSubview:movieController.view];

Comment: Are you trying to play the videos at the same time or one after the other?

Comment: @MatthewHallatt let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/2772/discussion-between-jasarien-and-matthew-hallatt)